# Insert a character into data returned from an xml request

Tags: jquery, xml, ajax

I am parsing an xml file using jQuery and need to be able to insert a hyphen into the data that is returned from one of the nodes.  So for example if the node is

```
<number>123456789</number>
```

and the parse function looks like:

```
$(xml).find("ITEM").each(function()
  {
    $("table").append('<tr>'+'<td>' + $(this).find("number").text() + '</td>'+'</tr>');

  });
```

How could I split and insert a hyphen after the fifth number so the output would look like

```
<td>12345-6789</td>
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var text = $("number", this).text();
text = text.substring(0, 4) + "-" + text.substring(5, text.length - 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to be different...

```
var number = text.replace(/^(\d{5})(\d+)\z/, '$1-$2');
```